# Home made Cider Over Carbonated what should i do with the other Bottles?

Tags: cider, brewing, over-carbonation, help

I have been brewing some home made cider and decided last weekend to crack it open! (has been in bottles for about 6 months) when a friend opened the bottle it basically exploded and send the swing top flying covering the ceiling in cider and leaving about 100 ml of the 750 ml bottle remaining!

My question: is there anything i can do with the remaining bottles to stop them from doing the same thing? or am i doomed to opening them outside and having little cider left?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Cool them down to as close to freezing as you can to make sure as much as possible of the CO2 stays in solution.

Then carefully vent the pressure from each one in a safe place.

If it's not done carbonating then I'd repeat the above every day until it is. (Edit: it's done after 6 months...)

Comment: Also an adjustable bottle capper can be used to hold the swing cap in when released and gently degassed.